# Application Insights custom metrics pricing

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, billing

I am looking at Azure Portal for my App Insights usage.

In the volume trends I can see that about 20MB of metrics ingested per day.

[image: Volume Trends]

But under estimated costs I see custom metrics estimated usage is at only a few bytes.

[image: Estimated Costs]

Why is there a difference in these numbers? Do they mean different things?

I can see custom metrics I log from the app in the `customMetrics` table, despite the usage staying at 38 bytes for quite some time now (atleast a week). I'm concerned if the monthly usage would jump when I hit the 150MB free limit.

Comment: This question is not really a Stack Overflow question since its nothing about programming. But I suggest you start of by reading the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/pricing

Comment: Yea had a look there and the pricing page. Both suggest customMetrics should count towards the 150MB free quote, despite the azure portal showing this discrepancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in query in backend. The product team has been fixed it and plan to deploy the fix by the end of next week. Please keep an eye on it. I'll update this thread when I get any feedback.

Comment: thanks Ivan. Does the fix mean metrics are counted towards the free limit after the fix? or would there be no change to pricing? (i.e metrics not counted unless "Enable alerting on custom metric dimensions" is tuned on ?)

Comment: @Madushan, the fix means that for the "custom metrics"(monthly usage) will show the correct value. And no charges for it(but it will be charged in future). Please note that, the metrics value in "custom metrics"(monthly usage) is different from the metrics value in "Data volume trends". In "Data volume trends", the metrics includes both custom metrics and standard metrics.

Comment: @Madushan, I checked it in my portal, I can see it's fixed. You can check it in your portal(if it's not fixed, please check it in the following days). And if the answer is helpful, please accept it as answer. Thanks:).

Comment: @Madushan, the fix means that for the "custom metrics"(monthly usage) will show the correct value. And no charges for it(but it will be charged if it's more than 150M in monthly usage). Please note that, the metrics value in "custom metrics"(monthly usage) is different from the metrics value in "Data volume trends". In "Data volume trends", the metrics includes both custom metrics and standard metrics.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. I can see the monthly usage has increased to 184bytes for me. (Will give it a few days to confirm though). Thank you for your help. Please update the answer if the situation changes.